# How to Save gmail attachment to SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, asp.net, gmail

Hi i have read my gmail by using Openpop.net like as [Here](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-and-read-email-messages-with-attachments-from-GMAIL-POP3-mail-server-in-ASPNet.aspx).

From this i can get and stored the mail data (from, date, subject, body) into sql server. But i need to know how to save the attachment into sql server.

Here we have fetch the attachment like as follows,

```
 List<MessagePart> attachments = message.FindAllAttachments();

    foreach (MessagePart attachment in attachments)
    {
        email.Attachments.Add(new Attachment
        {
            FileName = attachment.FileName,
            ContentType = attachment.ContentType.MediaType,
            Content = attachment.Body
        });
    }
```

In SQL SERVER My attachment table like as follows

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Email_Attachment](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[MessagId] [varchar](500) NULL,
[AttachmentFileName] [varchar](500) NULL,
[AttachmentContentType] [varchar](500) NULL,
[AttachmentContent] [varbinary](max) NULL)
```

How to save the attachment into sql table. the attachment whatever it is pdf,jpg,ppt,etc...
I need to know about, How to save and retrieve the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You can encode the byte array to a Base64 string before storing it in your database:

```
string encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(content);
```

After retrieving it from your database, simply decode it back to a byte array:

```
byte[] content = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encoded);
```